# drawing electron configuration (high and low spin)

Tags: chemistry

How does I create an image like the one shown under this text directly in the LaTeX document? I have tried with TikZ, but I can only make boxes with the arrows inside, and not exactly like the image.
I have to draw how the electrons are distributed in an d-orbital and it has to be as the shown here.

[image: electron configuration]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: As for [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228), would you like to post your code so far?

Comment: Related package: http://www.ctan.org/pkg/modiagram

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I understand, you dislike TikZ, but accept any LaTeX packages.

In the following solution all parameters are exemplary, as I don't know the proper usage of your orbital. You can certainly customize them.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{graphics}

\begin{document}

\def\orbud{\scalebox{3}{\sout{$\;\upharpoonleft \,\downharpoonright\;$}\quad } }

\def\orbu{\scalebox{3}{\sout{$\;\;\upharpoonleft \;\;$}\quad }}

All parameters are to customize

\bigskip

\begin{tabular}{c}
\orbud \orbu\\[2em]
 \orbu  \orbu  \orbu
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why not just a simple raised `rule` instead of striking out?

Comment: @percusse To make the code as simple, as possible, even if additional packages must be loaded. A simple version for a new user.

Comment: Thanks. I do not dislike the tikz, I just could not get it to be as I needed.
This is simpel, and does not fill much, which is quite nice.
I have been using LaTeX for a few years but simpel and easy and nothing fancy.

But thanks again :)

Comment: rule doesn't need `ulem`so you can remove even that.

Answer (score 2):

With `tikz`:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[line width=0.2pt]
    \draw (0,0) -- (1.8ex,0);
    \draw [arrows = {-Straight Barb[left,scale=0.5]}] (0.6ex,-0.6ex) -- (0.6ex,0.6ex);
    \draw [arrows = {-Straight Barb[left,scale=0.5]}] (1.2ex,0.6ex) -- (1.2ex,-0.6ex);
    \begin{scope}[xshift=1cm]
    \draw (0,0) -- (1.8ex,0);
    \draw [arrows = {-Straight Barb[left,scale=0.5]}] (0.9ex,-0.6ex) -- (0.9ex,0.6ex);
    \end{scope}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

When used inline with text,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
  Some text
  \begin{tikzpicture}[line width=0.3pt]
    \draw (0,0) -- (1.8ex,0);
    \draw [arrows = {-Straight Barb[left,scale=0.5]}] (0.6ex,-0.6ex) -- (0.6ex,0.6ex);
    \draw [arrows = {-Straight Barb[left,scale=0.5]}] (1.2ex,0.6ex) -- (1.2ex,-0.6ex);
    \begin{scope}[xshift=1cm]
    \draw (0,0) -- (1.8ex,0);
    \draw [arrows = {-Straight Barb[left,scale=0.5]}] (0.9ex,-0.6ex) -- (0.9ex,0.6ex);
    \end{scope}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here you may adjust the `baseline` suitably if you want.